# most basic laser diode driver?

Tags: laser, laser-driver, laser-diode

Is a simple LM317-based laser diode driver safe for powering a laser diode?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuMngik0GR8 (the diagram is at 1:37)
[image]

I've been told the the proprietary drivers offer some extra protection from very short spikes (on power up and shutdown) in the current which laser diodes are very sensitive to and might be damaged from. But isn't the LM317 regulator taking care of that itself already?

I've been told this from people who actually sell commercial laser diodes so I'm thinking they might be showing some bias.

Comment: I just *LOVE* it. circuit diagrams in YouTube videos.  Can there be anything in this world more *USELESS*?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: Crappy resolution, scroll through a MOVIE to look at it.  Compression artifacts.  I must be some kind of dinosaur.  I always want diagrams and project descriptions I can print out and work from instead of fuzzy videos that never show things from the right angle to see what I actually need to do.

Comment: I know where you're coming from but it's very readable in that video. But here's a screencap: http://i.imgur.com/eaburvP.png

Comment: So why not just put the screen capture into your post instead of expecting us to watch through the video to see it?

Comment: "watch through the video" - you don't have to, you move your mouse cursor to the search bar and click where you see "1:37". The video contains more info which I don't know is needed or not. Fair enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a regulated power supply, a simple resistor will do to take the laser above its threshold point. More complexity can involve a thermistor to lower resistance as temperature rises keeping the laser current at a slightly higher value at higher temperatures. Here is a typical laser characteristic for a device supplied by Hamamatsu: -

[image]

A more complex circuit would be needed if the laser were to be used as a datacomms device but this would involve only one extra inductor and a capacitor.

Going further, to higher powers and several manufacturers make chips that monitor the inbuilt photodiode inside a lot of lasers. They do this to protect the device from excessive currents.

Using an LM317 current limiting supply seems reasonable to me but the devil is in the detail and a circuit would be needed to be looked at for greater confidence (plus the data sheet of the laser).

Comment: @Andyaka Do you know any of LD driver chips for 5-100mW?

Comment: BTW the circuit diagram in the video is at 1:37 http://i.imgur.com/eaburvP.png  Laser data sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6-KC5wFXIJZGo3WFpjeWRwdHc/edit  Of course the circuit will be modified for the correct voltage and current.

Comment: The circuit looks fine and the laser is a beast. I only tend to work with sub 100mW lasers hence I'm calling it a beast!

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with the circuit you've shared is transients.

Some linear regulator circuits will tend to overshoot on turn-on, or allow input transients to pass through to the load. Here's the ripple rejection curve for TI's LM317:

[image]

You can see that the LM317 will do very little to protect the laser from transients with characteristic times below about 1 us. And an ESD event can easily have a pulse width as short as 1 ns.

And many laser diodes are quite sensitive to over-voltage and over-current. They may also respond very quickly to transients compared to other devices that you might connect to an LM317.

A good laser driver circuit should have ESD protection, transient protection, and a slow-start behavior.

These things are more important if you are driving a low-cost CD laser, or a high-speed telecommunications laser than if you are driving a high-power material processing laser. They may also be less important today than they were 20 years ago due to improvements in the robustness and reliability of newer laser designs.

Comment: Do you know what is typically used in these drivers for ESD protection, transient protection, and a slow-start behavior?

Comment: Unfortunaely, everybody seems to have their own favorite protection devices and circuits, based on experience. I don't know if there's "one right answer" for that.